# cant save django model object in database

Tags: django, django-models

I use `request.POST` content to save a model object after creating and authenticating a user.

the problem is that my user is created and authed but the model which extends that very users information `"school_info model"` in database is not saved while no error given. here is my code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny, ))
def login_api(request):
    post = request.POST
    user = authenticate(
        request,
        username=request.POST['username'],
        password=request.POST['password']
        )
    if user:
        school = school_info.objects.create(
            school_user=request.user,
            school_name=post['school_name'],
            school_manager_name=post['school_manager_name'],
            school_manager_phone=post['school_manager_phone'],
            class_count=post['class_count'],
            students_per_class=post['students_per_class'],
            daytime_importance=post['daytime_importance'],
        )
        school = school.save()
        login(request, user)
        return Response({}, status=200)
    else:
        return Response({}, status=401)
```

school_info model

```
class school_info(models.Model):
    school_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    school_manager_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    school_manager_phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    class_count = models.IntegerField()
    students_per_class = models.IntegerField()
    daytime_importance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I tried `ModelForms` and `obj.create().save()` too but both of them aren't working.

any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean the school object is not getting saved at all or it has no attributes saved. With the way you are doing it, it’s just creating lot of local variables, you are not attaching it to the model created.

Comment: "the model which extends that very users information in database is not saved" - which model are you referring to - `school_info` or some other one? If the latter, which model it is? Also the following line makes no sense: `school = school.save()` -  `save()` method does not return anything.

Comment: request has the correct headers and the imports are correct and I've registered model in admin. the objects can be created by shell or admin interface but not with this code only. I've tried serializing too but didn't worked..

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem, but `objects.create` actually calls `.save()` so you don't have to call it manually like you did

Comment: I only wanted to try every think. while i knew this

Comment: I mean i even have tried ```objs.create()``` itself only